# Display date and time in datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

Just a general question because after some research, I cannot seem to find an answer.

Is it possible to display both the `date & time` in a `datetimepicker` ?

I have a situation where the time must be selected independently from the date.

I know that a `datetimepicker` can display just the time or just the date , but I need to display together .

Hope there is an answer to this. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,Using DateTimePicker we can display both date and time together

Try like this

```
 DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
 DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh mm ss"
 MsgBox(DateTimePicker1.Value)
```

Or Else you need to set these Property in your DateTimePicker1 as

```
 Format = Custom
 CustomFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh mm ss"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using CustomFormat for DateTime:**

```
 DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "your Format"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 Private Sub DateTimePickerValueChanged(ByVal obj As Object, _

                                       ByVal ergs As EventArgs)

MessageBox.Show("Datetime :" + DTP.Value.ToString())
```

For more details see this post : http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/datetimepicker-control-in-vb.net